# Enterprise Chef Push Jobs

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I have configured enterprise chef with, reporting,push-jobs and RBAC packages.
The push-jobs server is installed and is verifies using buil-in tests `opscode-push-jobs-server-ctl test`.
The push-jobs cookbook is ran against the node to set-up the push-client service, which is also running correctly.
The problem is with the workstation. Knife-pushy gem is installed, but on running the command `knife node status`, the output shows `undefined/unavailable` against my node even when the pushy-client service is running on the node.

Please point out where the error might be.

Comment: This is a bug in the tool and should be reported to the support team at Chef.

Answer (score 1):

I raised this question internally and it is most likely a bug. We suggest opening a support ticket.